# Help on algorithm to place rooms on a limited space

Tags: algorithm, optimization, geometry

I'm working on a small house design project and one of its most important parts is a section where the user can give some info about how he wants his rooms (for example, a house with 10 x 10 meters, having a 3x3 living room, a 3x3 kitchen, two 4 x 5 bedrooms, and a 4x2 bathroom), and then the program generates a map of the house according to the requeriments made.

For now, I'm not worried about drawing the map, just arranging the rooms in a way they don't overlap (yes, the output can be pretty ugly). I've already made some searches and found that what I want is very similar to the **[packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problem#Different_rectangles_in_a_rectangle)**, which has some **[algorithms](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/rectanglepacker.aspx)** that handle this problem pretty well (although it's a NP-complete problem).

But then I had one more restriction: the user can specify "links" between rooms, for example, he may wish that a room must have a "door" to a bathroom, the living room to have a direct to the kitchen, etc (that is, the rooms must be placed side by side), and this is where the things get complicated.

I'm pretty sure that what I want configures a NP-problem, so I'm asking for tips to construct a good, but not necessarily optimal implementation. The idea I have is to use graphs to represent the relationship between rooms, but I can't find out how I can adapt the existent packing algorithms to fit this new restriction. Can anyone help me?

Comment: I believe the general name for this category of problems is *constraint optimization*, a subset of *constraint satisfaction*. This may aid your searching. I also wonder if you really want to solve this problem; there are so many more things that go into room positioning (e.g, which side does the morning sun hit, where do all the AC ducts, plumbing, etc. run?)

Comment: Indeed, it may be better to just make a snazzy UI that lets the user place their own rooms, while reminding them of their constraints.

Comment: If the user specify too many constraints and you're not looking for an optimal solution, you should use a 'constructive' algorithm. Build step by step room by room according to the constraints, and go back and change your previous choice if it doesn't work

Comment: @derobert Thank you for your tips, I'll search about it. And there are really many other things to consider when placing rooms, but this is not a real-world project (is a school project), and I may say I don't have the choice to change the proposal :(

Comment: @bdonlan I'm starting to consider this solution... in fact, I'm not the one who gave the idea of an "algorithm", so if I find that make this way is inviable, we'll probably have to do in a simpler way

Comment: @Ricky Bobby sounds interesting (and pretty simple) :D

Comment: @Luiz - it's harder than you think. How many possible positions are there, with two rooms of nonequal size adjacent to each other? Answer: Infinite :)

Comment: @bdonlan: I agree it can get pretty ugly when there are a lot of small rooms that you have to fit around a big one. But since a house usually has less than 10 rooms and less than 2 connections per room, and in general the connections are not that tricky, you will find a feasable solution with a construction algorithm pretty quickly.

Comment: @bdonlan hum... I think I don't have to consider all infinite ways, but this is a good question to think about. I was thinking in consider "linked rooms" as just one rectangular room (for algorithmic purposes), but it's pretty clear that it will make the wasted space pretty high :(

Answer (score 3):

I don't have a full answer for you, but I do have a hint: Your connectivity constraints will form what is known as a [planar graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planar_graph) (if they don't, the solution is impossible with a single-story house). Rooms in the final solution will correspond to areas enclosed by edges in the [dual of the constraint graph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_graph), so all you need to do then is take said dual, and adjust the shape of its edges, without introducing intersections, to fit sizing constraints. Note that you will need to introduce a vertex to represent 'outside' in the constraint graph, and ensure it is not surrounded in the dual. You may also need to introduce additional edges in the constraint graph to ensure all the rooms are connected (and add rooms for hallways, etc).

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this](http://www.andrew.cmu.edu/course/48-747/subFrames/readings/Stiny&Mitchell.thePalladianGrammar.pdf) interesting.
It's a grammar for constructing Palladian villas.

To apply something like that to your problem, I would have a way to construct one at random, and then be able to make random changes to it, and use a simulated annealing algorithm.